# Efficient way of selecting object created via operator

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I'm looking for an efficient way to select an object that is automatically created by an operator. Specifically, in my case, it is the `bpy.ops.hook_add_newobj()` operator that I use to hook a control point of a curve to a new Empty object.

What I came up with is

```
objs = bpy.data.objects.keys()

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = curveOBJ

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT', toggle = False)
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
curveOBJ.data.splines[0].points[0].select = True
bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT', toggle = False)
objs_new = bpy.data.objects.keys()

obj = [obj for obj in objs_new if obj not in objs]
```

And it works fine, but it is ceirtainly not an efficient solution, especially for scenes with lots of objects. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Thanks in advance to everyone,

Cheers

Comment: You can use lower level functions instead of operators where you get reference to the created object. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I did think about that, however, but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid to basically re-write the `bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newobj()` operator.